# Maven - moved code to new artifact; transitive dependencies issue

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Here is my situation:

- I created a new artifact in a library called 'web-ng-framework', and moved code into it from an old artifact in the library, 'web'
- I deleted the 'web' artifact

And here is the problem:

- ProjectA uses an older version of the library, and so it has a compile dependency on 'web'
- ProjectB depends on ProjectA
- **ProjectB uses the latest version of the library, so when ProjectB is built, it contains both the 'web' and 'web-ng-framework' libraries, causing a possible conflict**

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**

Would doing 'relocation' of 'web' to 'web-ng-framework' maybe work better? In ProjectA, I could include a dependency on 'web' so that Maven would see that what it really needs is 'web-ng-framework'. Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic solution to this problem is the 'Version 99' hack.

To do this, use the following in your root pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>your.group</groupId>
     <artifactId>web</artifactId>
     <version>99.0-does-not-exist</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then put an empty web-99.0-does-not-exist.pom and web-99.0-does-not-exist.jar in your repository.
This ensures that every project that inherits from this root pom will not get the old version of the web.jar anymore.

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution I used, basically.  For version, I used "2.0".  In my repository I uploaded version 2.0 with relocation information to point to the renamed artifact.

Answer (score 9):

When including ProjectA in ProjectB exclude web. Like this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>your.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>your.group</groupId>
       <artifactId>web</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: True, but I have many projects like ProjectB that include older versions of the library and are included in other projects, so I'd have to do lots and lots of exclusions.

Comment: Would doing 'relocation' of 'web' to 'web-ng-framework' maybe work better? In ProjectA, I could include a dependency on 'web' so that Maven would see that what it really needs is 'web-ng-framework'.  Would that work?

Comment: (this answer is for the first comment, not the second) Yes. Of course, the best solution would be to rebuild ProjectA but if that's not possible I think this is the only and best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [optional dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

This can be acheived by making `web` depencency optional in `projectA`.

```
<project>
  <groupId>some.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <!-- declare the dependency to be set as optional -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>some.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>web</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When declaring some other project that depends on `projectA` the `web` dependency will not be included.

```
<project>
  <groupId>some.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>some.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>some.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>web-ng-framework</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now `projectB` will only have a dependency on `projectA` and `web-ng-framework`, not `web`.